# 2nd level of CSS dropdown menu not working correctly

Tags: php, html, css

I don't know how to explain this correctly, but I have a CSS menu on my site and the first layer of it works fine, when you hover over a menu item the list appears as a dropdown.  But the sublists also appear instead of waiting for a hover.  If you go here:

http://www.negativeworld.org/test.php

and hover over "main" you will see what I mean, "test 1" and "test 2" should only appear when "test" is hovered over, but instead they appear right away when "main" is hovered over.

Here is my CSS:

```
/* Fix IE. Hide from IE Mac \*/
* html ul li { float: left; height: 1%; }
* html ul li a { height: 1%; }
/* End */

ul {
    background-image: url(design/banner_menu_fd_excel.png);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 140px;
}

ul li {
    position: relative;
    z-index:100;
}

li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width: 140;
    display: none;
}

ul ul  ul { position: absolute; left: 100%; top: -1; z-index:100; }

li:hover {
    visibility: visible; 
}

li:hover ul, li.over ul { 
    display: block;
}

ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}

ul a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background:#8A8987;
}

.user_box_name a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.user_box_name a:hover {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

And here is my menu:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="content.php" id="mainmenulink2" onMouseOver="bt_main.src=menu_main_on.src" onMouseOut="bt_main.src=menu_main_off.src" onFocus="this.blur()"><img src='design/menu/menu_main.png' name="bt_main" width="130" height="32" border='0' id="bt_main"></a>

        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="test.php">test</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="test.php">test 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="test.php">test 2</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <li><a href="content.php?tp=recenthot" class="menulink">Hottest (Recent)</a></li>
                    <li><a href="content.php?tp=alltimehot" class="menulink">Hottest (All-Time)</a></li>
                    <li><a href="content.php?tp=news" class="menulink">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="content.php?tp=review" class="menulink">Reviews</a></li>
                    <li><a href="content.php?tp=editorial" class="menulink">Editorials</a></li>
                    <li><a href="content.php?tp=podcast" class="menulink">Podcasts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="content.php?tp=roundtable" class="menulink">Roundtables</a></li>
                    <li><a href="content.php?tp=top ten" class="menulink">Top Ten Lists</a></li>
                    <li><a href="content.php?tp=comic" class="menulink">Webcomics</a></li>
                    <li><a href="content.php?tp=game" class="menulink2">Game Discussions</a></li>
                    <li><a href="content.php?tp=poll" class="menulink">Public Polls</a></li>
                    <li><a href="content.php?tp=etc" class="menulink">Etcetera</a></li>

                    <!--<li><a href="comicchoose.php">Comics</a></li>-->
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

I'm modifying code that the last programmer worked on so I'm not totally sure what I'm doing.  I tried looking up the solution to this issue but I kept running into a wall.  Does anyone know what the fix is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `>` after the `li:hover`

`>` selects the only first child (direct child) of the element. Your current code is saying to block (show) all `ul` on mouse over.

[Check this](http://userinterfacehome.blogspot.in/2012/11/css-selectors.html) for more information.

```
li:hover > ul, li.over > ul { 
    display: block;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hYZjp/)**

Comment: Actually I may have spoken too soon.  Everything works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but the dropdown won't work at all anymore in IE 9.  It worked fine when there was just the one dropdown under each menu item, but with the second level added it just dies.

Comment: @AndrewNee As I can't edit your entire code according to the browser compatibility, I would suggest you to go through this tutorial of my blog http://userinterfacehome.blogspot.in/2012/11/pure-css-dropdown-menu.html   According to this edit your code slightly

Comment: Sowmya thank you for the link, however, that blog post only contains menus with one "child" menu for each parent item.  My issue with IE 9 is only coming up when I have another level to the menu, for instance, in the page I linked above there is "main" as the parent, "test" as the first level child, and "test 1" and "test 2" as the second level children.  Adding in that second level is what is breaking IE 9.

Comment: @AndrewNee How about this http://www.blokeish.com/2011/03/horizontal-multilevel-menu-with-css-without-javascript/

Comment: Well now I got IE 9 working except that the "test 1" and "test 2" appear with a gap above them.  I'll check that blog tomorrow.  I'm so close to getting it working though!  I don't want to have to rewrite everything if I don't have to.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25508/discussion-between-sowmya-and-andrew-nee)